# get laravel search with multi options

Tags: php, laravel, search

I'm using laravel 5.4,

I want to get my website search result with multi options, currently I have `title,category & location` fields in my app and I want to let users get result by choosing any of these fields for example if one user just chose location base search be able to get the results without getting error of not filling other options etc.

The Issue;
Before I only worked on title field and everything worked just fine but when I define other two options `categories & locations` results will not return anymore, where is my mistake?

[image: screenshot]

this is my controller:

```
public function search() {
        $q = Input::get('q');
        $ads = null;
        $categories = null;
        $locations = null;
        if($q) {
          $categories =  Category::where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
              ->paginate(2)
              ->appends('q', $q);
        }
        if($q) {
          $locations =  Location::where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
              ->paginate(2)
              ->appends('q', $q);
        }
        if($q) {
            $ads =  Ad::where('title','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                ->orWhere('description','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
                ->paginate(2)
                ->appends('q', $q);
        }
        return view('search-result', compact('ads', 'categories', 'locations', 'q'));
     }
```

my route:

```
//search routes
Route::any('/search', 'HomeController@search');
```

my view:

```
@extends('layouts.view')

@section('content')

@if(isset($ads))
<h2>Search results</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($ads as $ad)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$ad->title}}</td>
            <td>{{$ad->description}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@else
no results!
@endif
@endsection
```

Update:

My controller relationships:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Events\StudentAdded;
use App\Ad;
use App\Company;
use App\Location;
use App\Category;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

Models:
Locations model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model
{

  protected $fillable = [
      'name',
  ];

  public function ads(){
     return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
  }
}
```

Category Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

  protected $fillable = ['name'];

  public function ads(){
     return $this->hasMany(Ad::class);
  }

}
```

Ad model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ad extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id', 'title', 'slug', 'image', 'description', 'address', 'job_title', 'salary',
    ];

    public function company(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
    public function category(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
    public function location(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
    public function employment(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Employment::class);
    }
}
```

Update 2:

Search Form:

```
<form class="form-inline myform" action="/search" method="POST" role="search">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="input-group" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Title">
              <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
              <input name="q" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
            </div>

            <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select category" class="sr-only mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Category</label>
            <select name="q" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select category" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
              @foreach ($categories as $category)
              <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>

            <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select City" class="sr-only mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">City</label>
            <select name="q" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select City" class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
              @foreach ($locations as $location)
              <option value="{{ $location->id }}">{{ $location->name }}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

Comment: On having a look at your controller, you're not making use of relationships. Share your model relationships and your search form.

Comment: I cannot find foreign key declaration in your table. What is foreign key for Location and Category in Ad model.

Comment: those are id's in DB tabels.

Comment: @robertnicjoo the models are good enough to help you with the query crafting. But we need to see your search form and input that gets sent to the controller to handle the search logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're appending the search query to your paginated links, you should probably use `GET` in your form. Secondly you're trying to pass all the search inputs with the same name. I've changed the input names to make the search easier. The code which I've shown below uses the 3 inputs to craft a query to get the appropriate ads. When any of the 3 inputs are provided, it's used to get the ads from the database. When more than 1 input is provided, then we apply all the conditions provided.

View

```
<form class="form-inline myform" action="/search" method="GET" role="search">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="input-group" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Title">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></span>
        <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>

    <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select category" class="sr-only mr-sm-2"
           for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Category</label>
    <select name="category" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select category"
            class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
            <option value="">Select category</option>
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <label data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select City" class="sr-only mr-sm-2"
           for="inlineFormCustomSelect">City</label>
    <select name="location" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="select City"
            class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
            <option value="">Select Location</option>
        @foreach ($locations as $location)
            <option value="{{ $location->id }}">{{ $location->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function search()
{
    $searchTitle = request('title');
    $searchCategory = request('category');
    $searchLocation = request('location');

    $ads = null;

    if($searchTitle || $searchCategory || $searchLocation) {
        $ads = Ad::when($searchTitle, function ($query) use ($searchTitle) {
                return $query->where('title', 'like', "%{$searchTitle}%")
                    ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$searchTitle}%");
            })
            ->when($searchCategory, function ($query) use ($searchCategory) {
                return $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($searchCategory) {
                    $query->where('id', $searchCategory);
                });
            })
            ->when($searchLocation, function ($query) use ($searchLocation) {
                return $query->whereHas('location', function ($query) use ($searchLocation) {
                    $query->where('id', $searchLocation);
                });
            })
            ->paginate(2)
            ->appends(request()->query());
    }

    return view('search-result', compact('ads'));
}
```

I'm not sure if you need the categories and locations in your search result page. But if you need them, then you can fetch using the ads relationship or fetch all the locations based on the input value. It's pretty straightforward and i think you can do that.

Comment: i tried these codes now the only thing has changed is that title search works same like before i add location and categories but if i leave title empty and just try to get results base on category or location will return nothing.

Comment: and i think there is another issue since i loop all categories and locations it will be always one option selected, how can I add an empty option in each of those so they just come to search circle only if they are selected.

Comment: Can you add `dd(request()->all());` to your search method and show the content when you perform a search with the inputs.

Comment: array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "aeh9i36cTZIVmdyz54C4wJe1WkFhrQNhLWSy6I95"
  "title" => "first"
  "category" => "1"
  "location" => "1"
]

Comment: @robertnicjoo the issue was that you're passing the category and location id, but trying to search using it's name. I based my query on your controller and didn't notice it. I've updated my answer to base the search using id. Also added a default option for select.